# Authorize client with a model other than User

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In DRF, You can create custom authentication classes and schemes. But in the end, all of them should return a tuple of `(user, auth)`. I have a special case where my endpoints are going to get called by multiple servers and each one of them has their unique secret, stored in the `Server` model and table in my app.

How can I implement authentication of these servers while the entity being authorized is not a User, but some other model?

This is my current code (not tested):

```
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

from .models import Server


class ServerAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        server_name = request.META.get('X_Server')
        server_secret = request.META.get('Authorization')
        if not server_name or not server_secret:
            return None

        try:
            server = Server.objects.get(name=server_name, secret=server_secret)
        except Server.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such server')

        return server, None
```

Comment: Maybe you should use permissions (authorization): https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ since you are not really authenticating anything if you cant identify a user from the request.

Comment: @ToniSredanović The thing is that I'm actually treating my servers as users, But they aren't users and have their own model. I kinda fixed my problem actually, but it's not that clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using the `auth` parameter to return my server and returning an anonymous user as the user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class ServerAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        server_name = request.META.get('HTTP_X_SERVER')
        server_secret = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        if not server_name or not server_secret:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Server authentication is mandatory')

        try:
            server = Server.objects.get(name=server_name, secret=server_secret)
        except (Server.DoesNotExist, ValidationError):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such server')

        return AnonymousUser, server
```